# Why does opening Mac Mail show a preview pane not the whole email?

Tags: mail.app, email, preview

On my MacBook OS X 10.10.3 when I used to open Mac Mail it would just display the entire message and there was more flexibility to deal with this or other messages. Now it seems to load a preview (constrained) version of the message with fewer options not the entire message as before. Looking on viewing preferences there is no obvious way to view email messages as before.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way to get the old view back is enable Classic Layout, prefs > viewing...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be relevant: An interface error appears to have crept into 10.10.4
The small dot on the Preview pane used to stop at top when dragged up.  Now it disappears under top of split window.  Solution?: carefully drag split window down from top again!...thought all my mail had gone!